# laravel 5 changing locale middleware via MenuItiem->Jquery->Controller->Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

So yesterday I did most of the work and now I am at the last stage of being able to modify the Locale (for use of language in Laravel 5) via Middleware.

The process is the following:

A user selects a language from a Dropdown menu, this clicked value is passed via Ajax to a Controller and the controller modifies its locale. But it doesnt end here. Before it was made through filters. Now it is the middleware. I have done quite a lot of discoveries about Middleware and I will include here. This last stage is what still is not making the expected change:

FULL CODE

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pick Language<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" class="choose-language" id="french" data-value="fr">Français</a></li>
<li><a href="{!!URL::route('index')!!}" class="choose-language" id="english" data-value="en">English</a></li>  
<li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" class="choose-language" id="spanish" data-value="es">Castellano</a></li>                                
<li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" class="choose-language" id="german" data-value="de">Deutsch</a></li>                                
<li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" class="choose-language" id="russian" data-value="ru">русский</a></li>  
</ul>
</li>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.choose-language').on('click', function () {
    var selectedlanguage = $(this).data('value');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'languagechooser',
        data: { 'locale' : selectedlanguage},
        timeout:3000,
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (savingStatus) {
            console.log(savingStatus);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('#errores').text("Error .");
        }
    });
});
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function languagechooser()
{

    \Session::set('locale', \Input::get('locale'));

}
```

MIDDLEWARE (PROBABLY WHERE THE ERROR IS)

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Language {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        app()->setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));
        return $next($request);

    }

}
```

UPDATES:

Following the helpful commments from Dutch Luceo I have progressed positively.

I have registered the class in the protected $middleware at the Kernel.php
I have added the: use App\Http\Middleware\Language at the top of my controller class. but I am now getting the message of Error from the Jquery Ajax, when it fails to do its job at the controller, it returns me" Error"

I dont know if the error is now in the Ajax or if there is something pending at the Middleware.

MIDDLEWARE KERNEL.PHP

```
 protected $middleware = [
            'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
            'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
            'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
            'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
            'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
            'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
 ----->     'App\Http\Middleware\Language',
```

UPDATE II

In order to pinpoint the Ajax error, I replaced the error function by this one which gives more details. The error says (I am offline), which I am not, so some connection between the controller and the Middleware seems to be misleading the Ajax or the Controller has to return something that Ajax expects.

```
error:function(x,e){
            if(x.status==0){
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            }else if(x.status==404){
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
            }else if(x.status==500){
                alert('Internel Server Error.');
            }else if(e=='parsererror'){
                alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            }else if(e=='timeout'){
                alert('Request Time out.');
            }else {
                alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
            }
        }
```

ROUTES FILE

```
Route::post('home', array(
    'as' =>'languagechooser',
    'uses' =>'LanguageController@languagechooser'

));
```

UPDATE III

I modified the URL in Ajax and wrote this instead:

```
url: {{URL::route('languagechooser')}},
```

now I dont get the "you are offline" error but still the locale is not modified..

Comment: why within handle function  has return $next($request);  even you have statement after that

Comment: did you register your middleware in the Kernel class?

Comment: @ Luceos: No I didnt, in fact that is one of the questions I asked, because while I am at this moment actually reading the Kernel.php file I dont know exactly how to write it.  For example, something like this?:

'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\Language',   and put it in the Protected $middleware?

Comment: `'App\Http\Middleware\language` would be correct, see your namespace and your classname. Please note you will have to have the language class in the `app/Http/Middleware` folder. Also note your class naming does not comply to the psr naming convention.

Comment: what is the name of your Language class file? Did you also change that to `Language.php`?

Comment: in your ajax call you are using the url `languagechooser` which is a relative path, from which url are you visiting this page and please also share your `routes.php` file

Comment: I modified the Ajax URL, now the error "you are offline" does not pop up, so that part must be fixed now.

Comment: I hardcoded the LanguagController, writing "en" instead of Input::get('locale') and it made no difference. That means, the controller is not either having any effect on the middleware work to modify the locale.

Comment: I want to give you the correct answer, but I cant if you dont post it under that mode. I have found an interesting hint into where I was failing. I was not activating the controller through the routes. So, created an artificial scenario, hardcoding the session = "en" instead of Input::get('locale') and then creating a test page where I both had a GET  and a POST to that controller. Then I went to that route, i returned, refreshed the page and I had the changes made.